# Postgresql - Auto vacuum is disables in conf file, but still everyday its running

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, vacuum, autovacuum

Im using Postgresql 9.2. I have disabled auto vacuum in Conf, but still, I can see this auto vacuum is running on few tables every day. Can anyone help me find out why its running?

Comment: "*I have disabled auto vacuum*" - why on earth would you do that? That's a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah I know disable auto vacuum is really bad, but it's very old server, Just want to know how its still running?

Comment: Probably to prevent wraparound - there should be something in the logfile.

Comment: Can you please give me a simple explanation about wraparound ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong,  So the transaction ID is almost filled, to prevent this Autovacuum is triggered.

Comment: Also just got to know,  anti-wraparound vacuum will take care of this.